# Creating templates for Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, template-design

I am very familiar with template creation for Coreldraw but I have never done this before in Illustrator nor did I see the question from a search.  How do you properly create a template and where should you place it to work well in Illustrator with the command <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>?  If I save the file as an `.ait` will it save it in the default location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click the **Templates** button located in the bottom left corner of the New Dialog window, you can see the location of the existing templates.

[image: template button]

Simply save your Illustrator files as .ait to that same location. Then clicking the **Templates** button will open that folder.

You can also always simply double-click any .ait file to open a new document based upon that template.

As for properly creating a template... essentially you can create any Illustrator file with any set up you desire and simply save it as a .ait file. There are no restrictions for template creating. The only thing I'd caution against is using linked files within the template.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Metis answer, you could also save any `.ai` file as a new template. Go to `File -> Save as Template..` as shown below to save as a new template.

[image: Illustrator File Menu]